# Cython Memoryviews -- From Array of Structs?

Tags: python, c, cython

I'd like to quickly fill with as few copies as possible a long array of structs that I'm receiving incrementally from C.

If my struct is only primary data types, like the following:

```
cdef packed struct oh_hi:
    int lucky
    char unlucky
```

Then the following works fine:

```
  DEF MAXPOWER = 1000000
  cdef oh_hi * hi2u = <oh_hi *>malloc(sizeof(oh_hi)*MAXPOWER)
  cdef oh_hi [:] hi2me = <oh_hi[:MAXPOWER]> hi2u
```

But once I change my struct to hold a character array:

```
cdef packed struct oh_hi:
    int lucky
    char unlucky[10]
```

The previous memoryview casting compiles but when run gives a:

```
  ValueError: Expected 1 dimension(s), got 1
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Cython? I'm aware that I could create a structured array, but afaik, that wouldn't let me assign the C structs straight into it.

Comment: This seems to be very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30035287/2588654) with numpy structured arrays. The problem is that cython does not seem to like mixing arrays with scalar values if the first item in a struct is a scalar. The workaround is just to rearrange the items in the struct such that there is always an array member/item first.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, just building a structured numpy array and then a memoryview works just fine.

```
cdef np.ndarray hi2u = np.ndarray((MAXPOWER,),dtype=[('lucky','i4'),('unlucky','a10')])
cdef oh_hi [:] hi2me = hi2u
```

The performance of this seems quite good and this saves a later copy if you need the data back in python. As per usual, the numpy version is pretty good. =p

Comment: This did not work for me. Maybe because I used fixed array of ```int32``` and not string 'a10'. I ended up flattening the structures.

Comment: I'll look into this, but how were you hoping these would be stored in the numpy structure?

Comment: for 10 integers, something line ('lucky',(np.int32,10))